# Colorbox without plugin and wordpress 3.5.1 gallery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gallery, colorbox

I have a problem.
I would like to integrate colorbox effect on a wordpress theme, but without plugin.
So I have this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/colorbox.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and this :

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();  ?>/js/jquery.colorbox.js"> </script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']").colorbox({transition:"elastic", maxWidth:"80%", maxHeight:"80%", slideshow:"true"});
});
```

So, with that, the single images work fine. They open in colorbox window.
But for the gallery, nothing.
So, I add

```
link="file"
```

in the gallery shortcode, like this, for example :

```
[gallery ids="54,53,58,59,66" link="file"]
```

With that, the image of the gallery open in colorbox, good.
But the problem is than each image open like a single image, no pagination (no Next image and Previous image)

I'm testing the site in local, so I can't have a link for you.
Wordpress 3.5.1
No plugin

I don't know how to resolve the problem.

If somebody know where is the problem, it would be very great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding a group class to the images so that you can link them together.

In this example the "group_name" is going to be part of the class of each image.  And instead of using the image type I used the same class to call the colorbox

```
$(".group_name").colorbox({rel:"group_name", transition:"elastic", maxWidth:"80%", maxHeight:"80%", slideshow:"true"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, Robert,

I am certainly not very good because I try your method and I can't arrive to work this.

So, I add your code, and so now I have this :

```
        <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']").colorbox({transition:"elastic", maxWidth:"80%", maxHeight:"80%", });
$(".group_name").colorbox({rel:"group_name", transition:"elastic", maxWidth:"80%", maxHeight:"80%", slideshow:"true"});
});
    </script>
```

(I tried too with this) :

```
$("a.group_name").colorbox({rel:"grou.....
```

and in the html post edition, I put this :

```
[gallery ids="54,53,58,59,66" class="group_name"]
```

I tried whith this too :

```
[gallery ids="54,53,58,59,66" link="file" class="group_name"]
```

But nothing. The problem is the same. No pagination.
I'm really hopeless :-)

[edit] : if I understand it's not work with [gallery].

With

```
<a href="http://localhost/.../......jpg" rel="group_name"><img   src="http://localhost/.../....jpg" width="150" height="100" /></a>
<a href="http://localhost/.../......jpg" rel="group_name"><img   src="http://localhost/.../....jpg" width="150" height="100" /></a>
```

It works fine, thanks.

But not easy.
Is it possible to have colorbox automatically on the WP 3.5.1 galleries with a class, for example, in

```
[gallery ...
```